# Can't access CouchDB Futon app with external URL

Tags: networking, couchdb, firewall, couchdb-futon

I can't access CouchDB Futon app URL from another computer. When I use `http://192.168.1.3:5984/_utils` in my computer, it works but when I access the same URL from another computer connected in the same network, the page is not loading. I can access other apps from another computer e.g. `http://192.168.1.3:8080` or `http://192.168.1.3:80`, only Futon app is failing. Any help?

I changed the bind_address to 0.0.0.0 in local.ini and 
I turned off the firewall but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a problem of cors, try to enable it 
https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CORS